# Computing (quickly) the multiplicity of a (prime) divisor

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization

#### Question

I have a fixed, prime `d` and an `n < 2⁶⁴`, and I want not only to compute whether `d` divides `n`, but also its multiplicity (i.e. the max `i` s.t. `dⁱ | n`).

I'm already using a [fast division](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251327/is-there-a-fast-divisibility-check-for-a-fixed-divisor), which costs one multiplication and one comparison to check whether `d | k` (and if so, get the quotient), but I still need to iterate that check `i` times if I do it naïvely.

Is there a solution that is sublinear in `i` ?

#### Context

I am trying to speed up an integer factorization tool, and after switching to [faster modular arithmetic](https://github.com/uutils/coreutils/pull/1529) (using the Montgomery transform), the table-based search for small factors uses [>30% of the runtime](https://nicolas.braud-santoni.eu/tmp/flamegraph.c6aaeecc.svg) (measured when factoring all integers from 2 to 10⁷; obviously, a good factoring tool should be fast on much larger numbers, but I'm trying to first squeeze out the obvious inefficiencies).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score -1):

For $p=2$, this is easy: On typical architectures `n & (-n)` is the largest power $2^i$ dividing $n$ and `(n & (-n)) % 67` uniquely determines $i$ (from a precalculated table).

For $p=3$, you might try to divide out repeated powers of $9$ and perhaps one additional $3$ in the end. This *almost* halves the time you spend with $p=3$, but in $\frac23$ of the (uniformly random?) cases you make two tests (though I think that you can get along with *one* common multiplication for $9$ and $3$ and only a second compare for $3$?)

For $p\ge 5$, I guess that divisibility by higher powers is unlikely enough to allow you to gain with a complex method compared to a well-cachable short piece of code.

Comment: Yeah, I already extract powers of two; no need for a precomputed table, `i = n.trailing_zeros()` and `n = n >> i` works fine (and `u64::trailing_zeros` is compiled down to [a handful of instructions](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/52bTXD))